# How to count a string occurrence,search in between a pattern for specific string

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I am working on a ksh script whose scenario is as follows:

I have a text file for students' reports which contains details of students
like:

```
Student_1
Name: ABC
Class:X
Head Teacher:SITA
Status: Pass 

Student_1
Name: ABCE
Class:X
Head Teacher:SITA
Status: Pass 

Student_2
Name:ABCD
Class:XI
Head Teacher:RYAN
Status: Fail

Student_50:
Name:MIKE
Class:X
Head Teacher:RYAN
Status:Fail
```

What I need to do is to

1. Find the number of students by counting the lines that start with `Student_N`;
2. Count how many students passed and how many students failed using the `Status:` line.
3. Find the name of students whose name starts with A.

I tried numerous things including:

```
sed -n '/Student_i<< Status/,/Status/p' students_details.txt >> report_card.txt
sed '/^Student_i<< Status/,/)/Status/$/!d/Status/s/^Student_i<< Status (///Status/s/);$//' students_details.txt >> report_card.txt
sed '/^Student_i<< Status/,/)Status$/!d;s/^Student_i<< Status (//;s/);$//' students_details.txt >> report_card.txt
sed '/^pass/,/);$/!d;s/^pass (//;s/);$//' students_details.txt>> report_card.txt
```

My desired output files are:

- For point 1:

  ```
  Student_1 : 2
  Student_2 : 1
  Student_50: 1
  ```
- For Point 2:

  ```
  Pass: 2
  Fail: 2
  ```
- For Point 3:

  ```
  Count of Students whose name starts with "A" : 3
  ```

Comment: What is it you are looking for?  You mention you want to learn.  However on this site you are likely to receive pre-chewed answers that may not advance your learning that much.  One tip; you seem to believe that "i" has some special meaning. In the samples posted "i" is nothing more than the letter "i".

Comment: Edited the question. Hope u will understand. At least give some pointers to resolve the issue, instead of ignoring it.

Comment: Since your data appears to consist of structured data records, I'd look at using `awk` or `perl` in 'paragraph mode' rather than `sed`. FWIW I don't see the relevance of the `ksh` tag here since you seem to be looking for a solution using external text-processing tools rather than the shell itself.

Comment: @steeldriver yes i am also working on different options like i had used grep -n -w filename.txt but still i am not fully satisfied.

Comment: OK so here's a freebie to get you started: `awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} END{print NR}'`

Comment: @steeldriver can you please provide a sample command since when i am running this it is giving a count only.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example of your input file (one that has actual numbers and data) and the output you would like to see from it. Also clarify your second point, it makes no sense, how can `Student_<>` be both odd and even?

Comment: @terdon i have modified the question.

Comment: OK, so what is your desired output from that file? One file? Many files? Please [edit] your question and add your exact output.

Comment: @terdon i provided output files needed

Comment: I tried to clarify (by the way, please don't ask so many questions ina single post). I don't understand point 1. Do you only want to count the students or also print `2` if they passed and `1` if they failed? You don't seem to be counting students anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would do the whole thing in Perl:

```
$ perl -00ne '/^(Student_\d+)/ && $count{$1}++; 
              /Name:\sA/ && $As++; 
              /Status:\s*Pass/ ? $pass++ : $fail++; 
             END{
                print "$_ : $count{$_}\n" for keys(%count); 
                print "Pass: $pass\nFail:$fail\n"; 
                print "Student names starting with A: $As\n"
            }' file
```

```
Student_2 : 1
Student_1 : 1
Student_50 : 1
Pass: 2
Fail:2
Student names starting with A: 2
```

If you insist on separate commands per operation, you could use:

```
$ awk '/^Student_/{a[$0]++} END{for(s in a){print s,a[s]}}' file
```

```
Student_1 1
Student_2 1
Student_50: 1
```

```
$ perl -ne '$pass++ if /:\s*Pass/; $fail++ if /:\s*Fail/;
     END{print "Pass: $pass\nFail: $fail\n"}' file
```

```
Pass: 2
Fail: 2
```

```
$ echo "Student names starting with A: $(grep -c "^Name:\s*A" file )"
```

```
Student names starting with A: 2
```

Comment: Nice answer using Perl. Since the original file had white-spaces in the second block, I'd add a `\s*` between `/^` and `(Student_\d+)`.

Comment: @Moreaki good point, thanks. I'm pretty sure that was just a copy/paste error though. Note how there are other places in the file that aren't uniform (some have `Name: foo` and others `Name:foo`). I am guessing the actual file is uniform and produced by some software tool.